# How to upload a review document from a document library workflow task?

Tags: workflow, document-library, sharepoint-server

I am trying to configure a Sharepoint document library with approve/reject workflow.  I understand the workflow aspects and the doc library settings but I can't see an ability for the reviewer to respond with APPROVE/REJECT **AND** upload a marked-up version of the document.
I want...

- userA to upload a document
- userA assigns the workflow task to userB
- userB reviews the document
- userB approves/rejects the task
- userB can upload a marked version of the document for userA to edit further < THIS IS THE PROB STEP

Any help really appreciated as I don't want to have a scenario where the marked up version of the document becomes a separate doc in the library.  I want it to stay linked to the original document passing through the workflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable versioning on your document library. When the reviewer uploads marked document, a new version will be created and then the other can update it and upload again.

In version history , you will be able to check all the versions in one place.